# Can the Google People API retrieve frequent contacts?

Tags: google-people-api

When I make requests I do not get frequent contacts, just saved. I understand this technically "is working correctly" but the google Contacts API documentation (which does show frequent contacts) states:

> Note: For read-only access to users' contacts, use the People API, which provides both contact and profile information, and does not use the older GData protocol.

Feel like that's telling me People API is a newer version of Contacts that supports the read only version of Contacts, so I'd assume it should exist.

Comment: I would expect [sortOrder](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list#sortorder) would include a `MOST_CONTACTED_ASCENDING` or some such value if this was a supported feature.

Comment: It does, but those do not include frequent contacts

Comment: Also, whoever down voted, please explain why

Comment: the docs I link to do not have the sorting feature I mentioned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36401355/1839532

Comment: @wasabigeek That answer isn't correct, as it doesn't show how to list them with contacts api.