# Is there any way to get other contacts from Google People API?

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Using 'people.connections.list' method of Google People API only returns contacts of Contacts Section. But i also want the list of Other Contacts. Is there any way to do so? Using Google Contact API however gives all the contacts but, it does not provide direct image link. We need to again loop all the contacts to get the image. This is very time consuming and not a feasible solution i guess.

Comment: I'm afraid that is the only way to get the "Other Contacts". As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401355/5995040), the difference between People API and Contacts API is People API lets you  fetch the contacts that are under the account "My contacts" while Contacts API fetches the other contacts lists ("Other contacts", "Most contacts", ...). You could also try using the [photo link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_contacts_photo) using Contacts API. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot, using photo link do give image in byte array but with a cost of another extra request to the api. I need to get all contacts with image. But, this extra request to get the image is making my application really very slow. I wish i could get everything with a single request to contact api.