# Google Contacts API with People API

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I fetched contacts from Google Contacts API. But some contacts have an empty title field. On Google Contacts web app these titles exist. I think that Google uses People API to retrieve name for this type of contacts. 
How can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the difference between the two api's is how and what kind of contacts they fetch. People API gets contacts under "My contacts" while Contacts API list all contacts including "Other contacts". See reference from [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386957/google-contacts-api-vs-people-api). I f you need the list from "My contacts" you can use the [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get). For reference, here is a [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) for google contacts api.