# Other contacts for People API

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

As well explained in this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386957/google-contacts-api-vs-people-api) it is not possible to fetch "Other Contacts" with People API. I would like to know if Google is planning on doing that or not at all? Since Go for example has no support for Contacts API but only People API, it would mean that we would lose the possibility to access Other Contacts, which is pretty annoying for auto-complete feature in apps using Google contacts..
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Contacts API vs People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386957/google-contacts-api-vs-people-api)