# Is Google Contacts API still available?

Tags: google-api

I am using Google's People API to fetch contacts associated with my contacts in Google. However, as has been pointed out elsewhere, that API does not access "Other contacts" which are available at https://contacts.google.com/other.

I'm looking for an API that will allow me to access that data. I tried the Contacts API per the instructions at https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/ which says:

> To retrieve all of a user's contacts, send an authorized GET request
>   to the following URL:
>
> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full

I tried this, replacing `{useremail}` with my own but only got an error. I am logged into my Google account.

Is the Contacts API still available?

Comment: You can use `default` in place of `{userEmail}` which will access the authenticated user's contacts. I haven't found a use for specifying an email address there since the request would fail unless the email matches the authorized token.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using some code to send an authorized request with api secret.

Comment: That's the correct way to do it. The OAuth flow returns a `code` to your app. This one-time `code` can be used with your `client_secret` to obtain an `access_token` from the OAuth server. Finally, the `access_token` can be used to authorize requests on the Contacts API. Good times!