# Retrieving all (Other) Contacts from Google Contacts API using gdata-python-client and OAuth2 token?

Tags: python, google-oauth, gdata, gdata-python-client

In the hunt to list all (to include `Other`) Contacts for a Gmail/GSuite user. The current `People API` does not support this functionality, noting the following threads:

- Found this thread here, confirming such change in the API: [Google Contacts API vs People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386957/google-contacts-api-vs-people-api)
- Google team noting it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/iLsrN23xF6g
- Referencing ticket request for prioritization here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757468

When diving deeper, it seems the Contacts API is still functioning and can be used via `gdata` https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/

However, based on the following repo (https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client), there's limited documentation on implementation using OAuth2 (`userID`, `token`, `refreshToken`), which is the current stumbling block to get the list of `Other Contacts`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The ticket has been Won't Fixed after no one replied to the Google employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this posting https://gist.github.com/jorilallo/3686737 from 7 years ago(?). The actual sample code below that I had to modify a bit to get it working:

```
import gdata
import gdata.gauth
import gdata.contacts.client
import json
import requests

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'  # Provided in the APIs console
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'  # Provided in the APIs console
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ACCESS_TOKEN' # given from a prior OAuth2 workflow, along with userID and refreshToken
REFRESH_TOKEN = 'REFRESH_TOKEN'

# GData with access token
token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(
    client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    scope='https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
    user_agent='app.testing',
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN)

contact_client = gdata.contacts.client.ContactsClient()
token.authorize(contact_client)

feed = contact_client.GetContacts()

for entry in feed.entry:
  entry.title.text
  for e in entry.email:
    e.address

# JSON with access token
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=%s&alt=json&max-results=50&start-index=0' % (access_token))
data = json.loads(r.text)
print data
```

Comment: Error: `Contacts API is being deprecated. Migrate to People API to retain programmatic access to Google Contacts. See https://developers.google.com/people/contacts-api-migration.`